# ESLint for Guard Clauses

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there an ESLint rule to detect if the code can be detected when it's not using guard clauses?
This is related to this post- https://elliotekj.com/2016/12/02/guard-clauses-in-javascript/

for example, this should **HAVE** a warning:

```
function doSomething(obj) {
  if(obj) {
    console.log('I did something');
  }
  return null;
}
```

This should have **NO** warning

```
function doSomething(obj) {
  if(!obj) {
    return null;
  }
  console.log('I did something');
}
```

I would prefer the latter. Please don't comment on the 'opinionated' aspect of this question. I just want to know if there is an ESLint specific rule or **something similar** that I can work with.

Or is ESLint even the right tool to detect/correct this kind of code style enforcement?

Thank you.

PS. I did do some research and did not found any rules that related to this my specific need on [ESLint Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/). Now, I'm just a newcomer JS developer and would like to know if I miss anything that I should have checked before I go any deeper into writing my own rule.

Comment: What does it mean for code to be "converted to ESLint"?

Comment: @JLRishe, thanks for the clarification, I changed "converted to" to "detected with", thoughts got mixed up. I wanted to automatically use eslint --fix at the start but decided that detecting it be easier

Comment: I don't understand your question. Both examples are valid JS, why should ESLint complain about them?

Comment: @Jonathan this will fall on [Stylistic Issues](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/#stylistic-issues) for ESLint

Comment: @mjabadilla come to [JS chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) and I'll explain

Comment: I see what you're going for, but my initial impression is that it's going to be very hard to algorithmically determine what's the main execution path and what is a guard statement.  It feels like identifying what a guard statement is requires an understanding of the intent of the code, which isn't going to be possible to algorithmically identify, consistently.

Comment: @Retsam thank you for your input. It's true and I think the approach for me should be done through peer to peer code reviews

Answer (score 0):

There is no ESLint rule that will catch that (up to v5.8.0). You provided the source yourself :)

I'm all in for guard clauses but I don't think this is a feature coming anytime soon because it's very context dependent and difficult to correctly identify it on all cases.

A sidenote from looking at your snippet, if you want to follow ESLint best practices, you should be returning a undefined/void instead of null in cases you don't expect a value to be returned (check https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return#require-return-statements-to-either-always-or-never-specify-values-consistent-return)